# Why does string.includes return an Error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to make a chatbot with Javascript. I'm using `if` statements to check whether the message includes a certain phrase and narrow down what the user is trying to say. I'm receiving an error at runtime which says `TypeError: toLowerMessage.includes is not a function` where `toLowerMessage` is the string I am checking.

I have tried looking into adding a `.toString` when I create the variable, but that has not worked. I have looked through all my code and don't spot anything particularly off about it.

Here is the line of code where I am receiving the error.

```js
if(toLowerMessage.includes("hi") || toLowerMessage.includes("hello")) {
```

I expect the `if` to only continue if the `.includes` statements return positive.

Comment: how your `toLowerMessage` looks like ?

Comment: check `typeof toLowerMessage` .

Comment: `var toLowerMessage = message.content.toLowerCase.toString`  +Code Maniac

Comment: You need to call `toString` by putting `()` `message.content.toLowerCase.toString()`

Comment: @MaheerAli keep going...

Comment: When I log the content of `toLowerMessage` I get `function toLowerCase() { [native code] }`

Comment: @Will, because that was a wrong suggestion. Check the answers instead.

Comment: You have to call `toLowerCase` itself, thats a function which returns a string. There is no need to call `toString` on a string then, so just do `message.content.toLowerCase()`

Comment: if you're using `toLowerCase()` to lowercase the string, it returns a string no need to call `toString` after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLowercase` is a function, so change to `toLowerCase()` so your expression should be

```
var toLowerMessage = message.content.toLowerCase();
```

ref https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLowerCase.asp

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! (I am quite new to Javascript)

Comment: Your welcome, feel free to accept the answer then :)

Comment: I will do that after the accept answer cooldown has finished :)

Comment: Why the `toString()`?

Comment: @tevemader you're right not needed..

Comment: As Aise:- w3schools resources are not up to date, you can use [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), also `toLowerCase()` returns string so no need of `toString`

Comment: I originally thought it would explicitly set the variable type to a string, but I'm new to Javascript and did not realise that this wouldn't be needed

Answer (score 1):

`toLowerCase` isn't a property, it's a function:

```
var toLowerMessage = message.content.toLowerCase();
```

You don't need `toString` because `toLowerCase` returns a string.

Also note that your `if` statement can be made simpler, and eliminate the requirement for this line altogether:

```
if (message.content.test(/hi|hello/i)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var toLowerMessage = message.content.toLowerCase();
```

is what you want.